# 'getContent' : not all control paths return a value "

Tags: c

```
`getContent` : not all control paths return a value
```

This is a warning I get while compiling a `C` program, where `getContent` is a `bool` method with website name and a buffer as its parameters and it is called recursively within that function if a desired page is not retrieved in the buffer.

How can I remove this warning?

Comment: Can you post a copy of your code?

Comment: Show the code. There must be at least one path through the function that does not `return`, which is an error.

Answer (score 7):

> not all control paths return a value

This warning occurs when, well, not all control paths return a value. For example, the following code may produce the warning.

```
int f(bool b)
{
    if(b)
    {
        return 42; 
    } 
}
```

In order to fix this warning, you should return a value from all control paths.

```
 int f(bool b)
{
    if(b)
    {
        return 42; 
    }
    return 50; //<--
}
```

Comment: Thanks Armen. This was very simple example to understand it better.